# Lead Conversion data population

Tags: lead-conversion

I am using out of the box functionality for Lead Conversion through the <kbd>Convert</kbd> button on the lead detail page. There are several custom fields on the `Lead` object which need to be mapped to `Opportunity` on conversion. The Lead object has 2 different Record Types and opportunity has 4 different Record Types. The custom fields on `Lead` and `Opportunity` are identical Text(100), and correctly mapped on the lead mapping.

The problem I face is that some of the custom fields are blank on the `Opportunity` record even though there is a corresponding value in the converted `Lead`. I understand that record types play a important role during the lead conversion. I tried using the default record type assigned to the user profile. Still the values on the opportunity are not visible. How can I debug further and discover the root cause?

Comment: Are you having issues moving data from a Lead to an Opportunity during conversion? I want to make sure I understand the issue before answering the question.

Comment: Yes @DanKowalski . The custom field data in Lead object is not mapped to the opportunity object on Lead Conversion

Comment: Have you looked at this in the sf documentation? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_mapleads.htm&type=0

Comment: Figured out that , it was not due to issues with Lead Map. There was a workflow which updated this field. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to further look at permission sets for that user & see if there is write access to those fields on Opportunity.